# How does the heat capacity of a calorimeter interact with the specific heat capacity of the water inside it?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, calorimetry

I saw this basic calorimetry question and it included the heat capacity of the calorimeter (1550 J/°C) but it also included that there were 150 g of water inside the calorimeter as well (4.184 J/(G°C). I saw that in order to calculate the total q, you add q of calorimeter to q of water. I'm having a hard time envisioning why you have to add the two instead of taking only the q of the calorimeter (isn't q of water included in the q of calorimeter?). The question stated that ∆T was equal to +1.211°C.

Comment: No, the heat capacity of the specific calorimeter being used must be determined experimentally. You can look up the heat capacity of water in a table.

Comment: Think of the calorimeter as the container.  Its heat capacity is fixed.   Then you add to this the heat capacity of the water, a figure that can vary depending on how much water you've poured into the calorimeter.

Comment: Oh ok, so let’s say that there’s a temperature change, would that temperature change be equal to both the water and the calorimeter?